# Can't uninstall Numpy on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to uninstall `numpy` on OS X `10.10.5`.

Here is what I've tried so far:

Uninstalling with `brew`:

```
brew uninstall numpy
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/numpy
```

Uninstalling with `pip`:

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
Cannot uninstall requirement numpy, not installed
```

The following `Python` library directories doesn't have `Numpy` files:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/
```

Printing the package path doesn't give the actual path:

```
In [1]: import numpy; numpy.__path__
In [2]: numpy.__path__
Out[2]: ['numpy']
In [3]: numpy.__file__
Out[3]: 'numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

The installed Numpy version is `1.8.0rc1` and I don't use a virtual environment.

Comment: Show me a few outputs:
$ which python; $ echo $PYTHONPATH; $ ls -l  dir_where_you_ran_ipython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the directory `/private/tmp/numpy` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ 
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-*.egg* 
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/f2py
```

If you want to verify where your packages are, you might try something like this:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Then you could try removing when you know the precise location of the package, say for example if you were looking for your Flask installation:

```
$ grep -R flask*.* /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried deleting the library files as you described but it didn't help.